# Python, pyinstaller raised an error as follows

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, gevent

when I ran the application, it raised error as follows.
My python version is 3.8.10 and pyinstaller version is 4.4.
How to deal with it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 360, in huaban.run.MainWorkPanel.start_download
  File "run.py", line 594, in huaban.run.MainWorkPanel.real_run
  File "scrapy\crawler.py", line 280, in __init__
  File "scrapy\crawler.py", line 152, in __init__
  File "scrapy\crawler.py", line 146, in _get_spider_loader
  File "scrapy\spiderloader.py", line 67, in from_settings
  File "scrapy\spiderloader.py", line 24, in __init__
  File "scrapy\spiderloader.py", line 51, in _load_all_spiders
  File "scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 83, in walk_modules
  File "C:\soft\VirtualenvFiles\huaban\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_pkgutil.py", line 71, in _pyi_pkgutil_iter_modules
    assert pkg_path.startswith(SYS_PREFIX)
TypeError: startswith first arg must be str or a tuple of str, not PureWindowsPath
```

Comment: There’s no error shown.. This just looks like relatively normal output while pyinstaller is running, building your package. What is the real problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in PyInstaller 4.5.

See [here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/6018).